# Object constructed automatically in java

Tags: java, android, oop

> [EDIT]
>
> > If getters in RolloParser is deleted, the problem is solved. But why
> >     getter method make the class constructed automatically?

I have a class named `RolloParser` you can see below. I use this class to parse a JSON file in my assets folder.

Problem is when I check this class is not `null` in my application class, I see that `RolloParse`has already been constructed. I wonder why?

**Line 7 never works but parser object is not null.**

**Application class method**

```
1- private RolloParser parser=null;
2- public RolloParser getRolloParser(){
3-
4-  //in first run, parser object is not null ???
5-
6-  if(parser == null){
7-     parser = new RolloParser(mContext);
8-  }
9-      
10-  return parser;
11- }
```

**Parser Class**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

public class RolloParser  {

    private String path ="www/android-device/rollo.json";
    private String extension =".ttf";
    private HashMap<String, String> iconMap;
    private HashMap<String, String> fontMap;

    public RolloParser(){
        System.err.println();
    }

    public RolloParser(Context context) {
        try {
            iconMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            fontMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

            JSONObject objTop;
            try {
                objTop = new JSONObject(AndroidUtils.ReadFromfile(path, context));

                String fonts = objTop.getString("fonts");

                JSONObject objFonts = new JSONObject(fonts);
                JSONArray icons = objFonts.getJSONArray("icons");
                JSONArray others = objFonts.getJSONArray("others");


                for (int i = 0; i < icons.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject objIcon = new JSONObject(others.get(i).toString());
                    iconMap.put(objIcon.get("family").toString(),objIcon.get("file").toString()+extension);
                };

                for (int i = 0; i < others.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject objIcon = new JSONObject(others.get(i).toString());
                    fontMap.put(objIcon.get("family").toString(),objIcon.get("file").toString()+extension);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < others.length(); i++) {
                    Log.d("json", others.get(i).toString());
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public HashMap<String, String> getIconMap() {
        return iconMap;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getFontMap() {
        return fontMap;
    }
}
```

Comment: First call to `getRolloParser()` will initialize the `parser`. What is the problem?

Comment: for such thing just make `parser` instance private static inside `RolloParser` class also getRolloParser() make static and move to `RolloParser` class and let getRolloParser take as parameter the context ... next use `context.getApplicationContext()` in line `objTop = new JSONObject(AndroidUtils.ReadFromfile(path, context));` instead plain context(Application context should be enough to get resource from assets and also live longer that Activity context) ... to get RolloParser instance use `RolloParser.getRolloParser(someContextMaybeActivity)` ...

Comment: @bigdestroyer when i call to getRolloParser() i supposed that parser object should be null at first time, but i is initilized automatically

Comment: it is really strange when i delete getter methods in rolloparser class   problem is solved. I is not initilized automatically. But why ?

Comment: @Selvin i dont want to use static method in this case. I want to use RolloParse in app context object which i created as a singleton object. Also when i delete getter methods it is not initilized automatically

Comment: @Selvin i edited the question by putting line in method. Please look at the getRolloParser() line 6. First running of this method, parser object is not null. so it is not going in if case.  Line 7 never works but parser is not null. Is it normal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have been calling the getRolloParser() method where it is getting initialised.To be sure put a break point in getRolloParser and check the parser would be null and then it would be  getting 
initialized

Comment: yes i call getRolloParse and there are break point also. When i look at parser object in method, i see that it is initilized already.

Comment: is it after executing this line of code or before parser = new RolloParser(mContext);

Comment: Yes before null check